# database connectivity of multiview

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-connection, multiview

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string insrt = "insert into book_mas_det(book_date,book_from,book_to,travel_date,return_date,adult_pax,child_pax,travel_class,contact_name,pnr_no,tot_amt,adv_amount,travler_rmks,agent_rmks) values (@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h,@i,@j,@k,@l,@m,@n)";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insrt, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", txtbookingdate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", ddlfrom.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", ddlto.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", txtdeprtr.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", txtreturn.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", txtadult.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", txtchild.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h", ddlclass.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", txtcontpername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@j", txtcontmobile.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@k", txtamnttocharge.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l", txtadvamnt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", txtcmnttrav.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", txtcmntagnt.Text);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    string display = "Booking Details is added successfully";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
```

this is my .cs code for the database connectivity.

Now my problem is, I have used MultiView in which there are 3 view,for the first view I have done done the naming conventions and I have done the database connectivity like this and it's working. But for the second view i cannot give the same names like `ddlfrom`,`ddlto`,etc...so how to do the database connectivity for the second view...do I have to add another function or click event for second view connectivity or do I have to add some conditions in my given function or ..some other different ways to connect all the views to my database.

Answer (score 0):

if you use multiview, each view behaves like a page, what is the need of using ist view button in second view,
otherwise it the button, controls and the functionality is same  then change the dropdown lists names in the design to ddlfrom and ddlto then you can use the same,
or else if the dropdown lists are required fields then use if condition.

Comment: i have same fields in diffrent views.for example in view1 i have from,to,departure and etc..in view2 i have all the things of first view except some...so when i cannot use same naming convention for both the views so how can i connect my view2?...by giving any other function like i have given for view1 or something else..?

Comment: when add parameters check with if condition for the controls those id's are different in both the views and then add parameters

Comment: u mean in the same funtion..?

Answer (score 0):

for example if you are in second view

```
if(ddlfrom.selectedindex>0)
{
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", ddlfrom.SelectedItem.Text);
}
else 
{
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", ddlfrom2.SelectedItem.Text);
//assume ddlform2 is 2nd views dropdownlist.
}
```

so form above in second view ddlform.selectedindex will be 0 so the method takes 
parameters as ddlfrom2.SelectedItem.Text, it is somewhat best for you.

Comment: but for this i have to change the names of my textboxex in view2 as ddlfrom and ddlto and so on, so its giving error that this name is been already used...

Comment: Naveen, no need to change the names of your controls, in the button click just check the vlaues of the controls if view1 values are not null then pass parameters as view1 values otherwise view2 values just like above code.

Comment: do i need to hamper my above codes like the way u told...or shud i reatin that code and add ur codes separately in the function.??..can u pls modify my codes in a process which i shuld follow...it would be of graet help...thanks..

Comment: you have already written your code so just copy and paste it,

Comment: i mean what i have written is for view1..now what u told me is for view2 right..???...so do i need to right ur codes separately below my codes..?..that is what i am trying ask..thanks for quick reply..:)

Comment: what u said is helpful for two views..what to do if i have to connect my third view also...??

Comment: ya do it separately in the same method.

Comment: then simply use nested if condition,